# Best IDE for Java Network Programming

Tags: java, network-programming

I'm going to develop a network application, using Java, for my University project.  I have used Netbeans previously for other Java development, but for this special development project, I don't know what is the best IDE that I can use.

I will be getting the IP addresses and connecting to the machines and will be doing some socket programming apps. What is the best IDE for that kind of application? I will be working using that IDE for about 6+ months, so it's better if it is a good one with usability.

Comment: Take your pick.  NetBeans or Eclipse.  Otherwise, it's Emacs or VI.

Comment: There's no real one true answer to this question which is simply a variant on which IDE is "best".  The answer is whichever one you are most productive in.

Comment: hi thanks for the openions. i am mostly familier in netbeans environment. familier the better is it? :)

Comment: What does "best" mean for you?

Comment: You should check jetbrains official student bundle offer. You can get online free student licence in 20 seconds for all these ides. [https://www.jetbrains.com/student](https://www.jetbrains.com/student/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use eclipse and then from this page http://www.eclipse-plugins.info/eclipse/plugins.jsp?category=Network find networking plugins that suites you most and install them.

Some networking plugin that you can find on that page are:

- Netwiser: a unique platform for network software development
- parfumball: a Java based network analyzer and packet sniffer

Comment: i have experience with eclipse only for php development, will try this also and see... :) thanx!

Comment: have tried it with the plugins , it's ideal... thanx for the great help...! :)

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ IDEA is free for Java SE projects, and my coworkers and I really love it.

Comment: it's a commercial one isn't it? hmmm... i'm still a student, can't afford that. :(

Comment: There's a pared down free version that's not bad.

Comment: is that so.. then i will try it and see.. :)

Comment: The commercial (aka "ultimate") version is mostly for Java Enterprise development.  IntelliJ IDEA community edition is fully-featured and not limited in any way for plain Java and Android development.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend IntelliJ IDEA.  It's generally considered the one to go for at my university.  I've been using it predominantly for networking programming for 4 or 5 months now.  It has a ton of productivity hints and tools.  But it is nevertheless very easy to use, tidy and efficient.

Comment: And yes, there is a "community supported" free version, which is the one I am using.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ free version. It's even better than the full version for your purpose.